# Promql when a PromQL + duration would be firing

Tags: prometheus

I was wondering if it's possible to acheive with PromQL:

Given an promql, and duration produce a graph of when it was active for the duration.
This is so you could retroactively see when a promQl would have produced alerts.

I thought doing something like this:

```
count_over_time(
   ($PROMQL)[$DUR:15s]
) >= ($DUR / 15s)
```

But it misses this case:
[image]